# Bash crashes when running common commands

Tags: bash, top, crash

Open Bash, run Top, and about 1/3 times, bash just closes. The other 2/3 times, it runs properly. The same thing occurs with other commands like "clear" or "/sbin/ifconfig"

Any ideas what may be causing this or how I can start investigating for the cause? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Have you tried running bash inside a bash to test whether only the inner bash crashes and not the whole terminal? Have you tried an other shell, e.g. dash?

Answer (score 4):

To investigate that problem, you could log in on a text console and run another `bash` instance there with your common program. The idea is that, if the `bash` instance terminates abnormally, you get a message printed to the console telling you why that happened.

If you cannot reproduce the error that way, you could open a terminal emulator and then open another terminal emulator from the terminal you just opened. Then, you can run the commands in the second terminal window and, if it gets closed abnormally, you may get a message telling you why that happened in the first terminal window.

Alternatively, you could run your common command in a shell other than `bash` to see, whether you can then reproduce the error, too.

If you have found the program that may cause the crash, you could install the debug information for it (if available) and then run that program within a debugger to get the location that causes the program to crash.

Comment: Also worth a shot: Running bash inside `gdb`.